# Can't access SNMP stack on rasp pi through router from WAN

Tags: router, forwarding, snmp, port

**Background**

I am running the following

- On my laptop the very latest version of arch linux with all the latest updates. It is from this laptop that I am querying an SNMP stack on a rasp pi

  `$ uname -a 
   Linux 4.20.13-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Feb 27 19:10:28 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- On a raspberry pi I am running raspian with all the latest updates.

  `$ uname -a
   Linux raspberrypi 4.14.98-v7+ #1200 SMP Tue Feb 12 20:27:48 GMT 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux`
- On the raspberry pi I am running an SNMP stack with configuration as follows

  - `$ sudo apt-get install -y snmp snmpd`

    `$ snmpd -v`

    `NET-SNMP version:  5.7.3`
  - The /etc/snmp/snmp.conf file is empty
  - The /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf file contents are pasted below

**Issue Description**

I am unable to get the `snmpstatus` command to work from the WAN ie while away and accessing the LAN remotely from across the internet. The command that won't work from the WAN side but will work from the LAN side is

`snmpstatus -v1 -c public my_dydns.org:1234` (as a result of this command nothing is displayed).

From the LAN side of the router the same command works as expected
`snmpstatus -v1 -c public my_dydns.org:1234`
gives the following correct output:
`[UDP: [94.94.94.94]:1234->[0.0.0.0]:40866]=>[Linux raspberrypi 4.14.98-v7+ #1200 SMP Tue Feb 12 20:27:48 GMT 2019 armv7l] Up: 15:33:34.58`

I have set-up my home router so that the external WAN facing port 1234 port, port forwards to 192.168.1.30 port 161 which is the SNMP stack on the rasp pi.

I know that my dydns and port forwarding work well becasue the same snmpstatus command used to get the SNMP status of a printer on the same LAN, accessed from the WAN, using a similar port forwarding regieme works just fine.

Below is my snmpd.conf file as use on the rasp pi.
The snmp.conf file exists and is empty.

**Contents of /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf pasted below**

`agentAddress udp:161,udp6:[::1]:161`

`# below allows any ip in the range 192.168.1.0 to 192.168.1.254 access to this SNMP, including the router at 192.168.1.1`

`rocommunity public  192.168.1.0/24`

`# allows port forwarding through the router from the WAN (ie the outside side of the router)`

`rocommunity public me.my_dydns.org`

Comment: Is that 1234 TCP or UDP?

Comment: On the port forwarding both. Should I change to UDP only?

Comment: Both work, the issue is another I think....will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

That IP address on the SNMP file is wrong. However, it is already included in 192.168.0/24, as the remark correctly mentions "including the router". e.g. you can comment out the line `rocommunity public me.my_dydns.org`

Nevertheless, it is not recommended to have SNMP services presented on Internet exposed interfaces for security reasons. Much less SNMP with v1/v2 authentication, where authentication is not encrypted.

I would advise setting up a VPN for talking SNMP over a VPN.

However, as far as I remember, some protocols are not NAT friendly, and SNMP is not one of the most NAT friendly. e.g. SNMP does not work well over NAT. It might or not work, and in this case, probably not.

I would advise setting up a VPN for talking SNMP over the Internet.

As an example with Cisco equipment:

> Network Address Translation > NAT Issues
>
> Table 4-1 IP Traffic Types/Applications Supported by Cisco NAT
>   Traffic Types/Applications Not Supported SNMP

PS. In enterprise equipment they have inspectors/specialized agent that rewrite SNMP packets for it to work over NAT.

Comment: Thanks @rui-f-ribeiro. SNMP port 161 is not blocked by the ISP as I can access a different SNMP device - a printer - from the WAN that is on the same LAN. So that is not the problem.

Comment: @Kes Do not fixate on that part, is just a recommendation. See what I have written, especially  in the 2nd paragraph please.

Comment: Thanks @rui-f-ribeiro. I have also tried testing for a changing dydns dymanic IP. It's not that either becasue I have tested that the public IP has not changed at the time I start the snmp deamon. (I do accept that come time that could become a problem but it's not with an other SNMP device as outlined above)

Comment: IS that 1234 TCP?

Comment: I have just tried router port forwarding set up as UDP only, TCP only and TCP & UDP as  was previously set-up. Change this setting gives no improvement.

Comment: It does not. SNMP does not work over NAT, which is what your router  is doing to reach the internal SNMP server.

Comment: SNMP works over port forwarding to my HP LaserJet printer with a JetDirect network card ! I can do an `snmpstatus` command from anywhere on the WAN.

Comment: Jetdirects never implemented things right, but it is an off-remark. What I am trying to say, is that is a known problem - I searched expressly for vaguely remembering it either, did not stumble on it either.

Comment: Is there a work around?

Comment: I always used VPNs/did it on internal networks. UDP is not supposed to be used over WAN, I guess vendors do not worry much about implementing it.

Comment: I can also do an `snmpstatus` query of router uptime from the WAN

Comment: Router for itself is not doing NAT. Dinner time here!

Comment: It's a long time since I did a VPN. Have to look that up

Comment: Hi @rui-f-ribeiro, thanks for your replies. My feeling is that SNMP over NAT is possible, just as it is with HP JetDirect cards. If anyone has thoughts on how SNMP with NAT can be implemented on linux please let me know..

Comment: HP might just have a sloppy implementation that does not care about which values it is fed...it does not mean much. Try to use `snmpdump` to debug what arrives at the SNMP side from the internet.